# How to solve the problem of sending a mutable list to another activty listview or recycleview in andoid studio Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I just want to make a home screen with four cards, and when you click on one, it takes you to a different screen or activity with its details!
for example : 
as shown below, I want to click on Villa card and it navigate to the screen that hold a list of villas
So the main idea is that I want to make one mutable list type of data class just like this:

`data class details (var id:String, var image:Int, var title:String)` 
this form: 
`var data=mutableListOf( //my code )` 
please tell me how to make something just like this or send me link of tutorial ! 
[image]

I have tried a sendig the muteable list to another mutable list that hold the id of listview, and I don't know really what went wrong !

Comment: First, implement serialization for your data class and then pass this class object to another  activity using putParcelableExtra.

Answer (score 0):

Create a data class named details with the properties that you want.
Create the objects you need and add them to a mutable list.

ie

```
val list = mutableListOf<Details>().apply {
add(Details(id = "1243", image = R.drawable.icon, title = "dog")}
```

you can add as many as you want.